# Фасетная навигация (статья)

Tags: навигация

Как-то попалась мне шикарная статейка по фасетной навигации и я, нуб, не сохранил ни её, ни даже ссылку. В статье подробно рассматривались различные способы реализации, сравнения моделей: их плюсы, минусы, производительность и прочие полезности. Сейчас возникла необходимость перечитать, а гугл всякую чушь выдает. Если вдруг кому попадалась или сохранена на компе такая статья, то просьба поделиться.